# WIX how to open custom UI

Tags: c#, user-interface, wix, installation, windows-installer

I have my own UI for the installation (using SharpSetup). The problem is, that when I double click the msi file the UI doesn't appear => Same when I uninstall it. To see the UI I have to double click my UI progject => gui.exe

What I'm looking for is:

is it possible to start the UI when I double click the msi file? 
if it's possible=> how can I do this and what do I have to include that the UI also appears if I uninstall it (add/remove Programs) ???

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [EmbeddedUI](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_embeddedui.htm) element in order to specify the file where you have the custom UI.

Example (where the custom UI is inside a dll):

```
<UI>
    <EmbeddedUI Id="EmbeddedUI.dll" SourceFile="..\EmbeddedUI\EmbeddedUI.dll"/>
</UI>
```

Once you do that, you'll have to provide dialogs for every action, since none of the default stock ones will run anymore.

About the uninstall, if i remember correctly the Custom UI will show up only in the repair process, so you could trigger a Repair instead of uninstall to show the ui and uninstall from there. The Uninstall process directly should uninstall the application with the default UI (progress bar with uninstalling)

According to MSDN : "*The custom UI DLL, in this example embedui.dll, should export the user-defined InitializeEmbeddedUI, EmbeddedUIHandler, and ShutdownEmbeddedUI functions.*"

You can see more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc542588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the response,

I added the <UI> -Tag in my WIX File and created a gui.dll which implements IEmbeddedUI. 
IEmbeddedUI includes the methods (Initialize,ProcessMessage, Shutdown). I'm not quite sure but are those the methods which are required for th dll? 

the problem is, that none of this methods gets called

Comment: @TimTiTim I've edited the answer with a link to MSDN example about EmbeddedUI. Those are the required methods in order to show your custom UI. I've previously done this using C++ and MFC and it was working ok.

Comment: thanks for that update, i saw that one too. I'm using WPF, and I added those methods too. But it doesn't work.  Isn't there a possibility to define the entrypoint for the GUI dll in the WIX file?

Comment: @TimTiTim As far as i know, no, you can't set the entry point for the GUI. You just implement those functions and MSI will call them when required. You can use a tool like ORCA to check the output msi file and see if the correct entries are added to the MsiEmbeddedUI table.

Comment: I just checkt the msi file with ORCA. There is an entry for MsiEmbeddedUI and this entry contains the expected name of the dll. But still the InitializeEmbeddedUI method doesn't get called. Maybe I still don't have the right methods in my dll.. My methods looks like this:  public bool InitializeEmbeddedUI(Session session, string resourcePath, InstallUIOptions internalUILevel)     public MessageResult EmbeddedUIHandler(InstallMessage messageType, Record messageRecord)       AND    public void ShutdownEmbeddedUI(). and I'm using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll

Answer (score 0):

SharpSetup uses external UI, not embedded UI. In typical scenario the msi file does not contain any UI so what you are observing is very much expected. However, you should not deploy the standalone .msi file to the client, only the Installer.exe file that contains all required files (including the .msi file and gui.exe).